# How to arrange divs vertically using CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, footer

I have this simple footer, I want to arrange col-md-8 above the col-md-4 at the media breakpoint of 720px(max.). I am new to CSS, How can I do this with CSS? **Please Run the snippet**

```css
/* <================== Footer ================> */

/*--- Footer Copyright ---*/
footer {
    background-color: #5A5A5A;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
}

footer .col-md-8 ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
}

footer .col-md-8 ul>li {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

footer .col-md-8 ul>li>a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
     
}
```

```html
<!-- <======================== Footer ======================> -->
  <footer class="mt-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">

        <!-- Footer Copyright -->
        <p class="ml-4 mb-0">Copyright <i class="fa fa-copyright"></i> 2020 Swan. All Rights Reserved.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 pull-right">

        <!-- Footer Navigation -->
        <ul class="mr-4 mb-0">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Private Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `order-first order-md-2` bootstrap classes to reorder the columns:

```css
/* <================== Footer ================> */

/*--- Footer Copyright ---*/
footer {
    background-color: #5A5A5A;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
}

footer .col-md-8 ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
}

footer .col-md-8 ul>li {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

footer .col-md-8 ul>li>a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- <======================== Footer ======================> -->
  <footer class="mt-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">

        <!-- Footer Copyright -->
        <p class="ml-4 mb-0">Copyright <i class="fa fa-copyright"></i> 2020 Swan. All Rights Reserved.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 order-first order-md-2">

        <!-- Footer Navigation -->
        <ul class="mr-4 mb-0">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Private Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```